# Can't change the whole background color for a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background

I can't change the whole background color for a button. I change it in the properties.

Does someone know how to fix this?

[image: Klick this link to see a picture of this problem]

Comment: That's the border, change the button to Flat and set it's border size to 0 (zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alter the properties highlighted:

[image]

It will give you a button like this (I had mine red):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set a combination of properties:

```
this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

and you'll get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that's because of the button's flat style,
change the FlatStyle to Flat,

and in FlatAppearence change BorderSize to 0 to get rid of the border

[image]